# iOS: UIActivityIndicator in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, xcode, search, uisearchbar, uiactivityindicatorview

Is it possible to display an UIActivityIndicator in the UISearchBar while searching?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can.

When start searching create an activity indicator and add it as the subview of `UISearchBar` using `addSubView` method. When you finish the search remove it from the search bar using `removeFromSuperView` method.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
//set frame for activity indicator
[searchBar addSubview: spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];
```

Refer this link for an alternative [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209842/replace-bookmarkbutton-with-activityindicator-in-uisearchbar).

Answer (score 17):

Update for **iOS 13.**

[image: ios13]

You can use below extension in Swift 4+.
Usage:

To show activity : 
**`searchBar.isLoading = true`**

To hide activity : 
**`searchBar.isLoading = false`**

**UISearchBar Extension**

```
extension UISearchBar {

    public var textField: UITextField? {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            return self.searchTextField
        } else {
            let subViews = subviews.flatMap { $0.subviews }
            guard let textField = (subViews.filter { $0 is UITextField }).first as? UITextField else {
                return nil
            }
            return textField
        }
    }

    public var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView? {
        return textField?.leftView?.subviews.flatMap{ $0 as? UIActivityIndicatorView }.first
    }

    var isLoading: Bool {
        get {
            return activityIndicator != nil
        } set {
            if newValue {
                if activityIndicator == nil {
                    let newActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
                    newActivityIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)
                    newActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
                    newActivityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                    textField?.leftView?.addSubview(newActivityIndicator)
                    let leftViewSize = textField?.leftView?.frame.size ?? CGSize.zero
                    newActivityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: leftViewSize.width/2, y: leftViewSize.height/2)
                }
            } else {
                activityIndicator?.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The best answer

Comment: It is a great workaround but doesn't look great on the latest iOS. Do you have a way to make it look good on iOS 11 and translucent navigation bar?

Answer (score 5):

Found none of the advertised solutions worked well for iOS13... here is my own, which subclasses the Search Bar and should be more robust for future use

```
class SearchBar: UISearchBar {

    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView?
    
    var isLoading: Bool {
        get {
            return activityIndicator != nil
        } set {
            if newValue {
                if activityIndicator == nil {
                    
                    guard let leftView = searchTextField.leftView else {
                        return
                    }
                    
                    let ai = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .medium)
                    ai.frame = self.convert(leftView.frame, from: leftView.superview)
                    self.addSubview(ai)
                    
                    ai.startAnimating()
                    leftView.isHidden = true
                    activityIndicator = ai
                    
                }
            } else {
                activityIndicator?.removeFromSuperview()
                activityIndicator = nil
                
                guard let leftView = searchTextField.leftView else {
                    return
                }
                leftView.isHidden = false
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I think this is a better approach especially that the search bar's background color changes from style to style and more bullet proof to future UI updates!